# Different results for linalg.norm in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, feature-extraction, euclidean-distance

I am trying to create a feature matrix based on certain features and then finding distance b/w the items.
For testing purpose I am using only 2 points right now.

data : list of items I have

specs : feature dict of the items (I am using their values of keys as features of item)

features : list of features

This is my code by using numpy zero matrix :

```
import numpy as np
matrix = np.zeros((len(data),len(features)),dtype=bool)
for dataindex,item in enumerate(data):
    if dataindex > 5:
    break
specs = item['specs']
values = [value.lower() for value in specs.values()]
for idx,feature in enumerate(features):
    if(feature in values):
        matrix[dataindex,idx] = 1
        print dataindex,idx
v1 = matrix[0]
v2 = matrix[1]
# print v1.shape
diff = v2 - v1
dist = np.linalg.norm(diff)
print dist
```

The value for dist I am getting is 1.0

This is my code by using python lists :

```
matrix = []
for dataindex,item in enumerate(data):
    if dataindex > 5:
        f = open("Matrix.txt",'w')
        f.write(str(matrix))
        f.close()
        break
    print "Item" + str(dataindex)
    row = []
    specs = item['specs']
    values = [value.lower() for value in specs.values()]
    for idx,feature in enumerate(features):
        if(feature in values):
            print dataindex,idx
            row.append(1)
        else:
            row.append(0)
    matrix.append(row)

v1 = np.array(matrix[0]);
v2 = np.array(matrix[1]);
diff = v2 - v1
print diff
dist = np.linalg.norm(diff)
print dist
```

The value of dist in this case is 4.35889894354

I have checked many time that the value 1 is being set at the same position in both cases but the answer is different.

May be I am not using numpy properly or there is an issue with the logic.
I am using numpy zero based matrix because of its memory efficiency.

What is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

It's a type issue :

```
In [9]: norm(ones(3).astype(bool))
Out[9]: 1.0

In [10]: norm(ones(3).astype(float))
Out[10]: 1.7320508075688772
```

You must decide what it the good norm for your problem and eventually cast your data with `astype`.

[`norm(M)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html) is `sqrt(dot(M.ravel(),M.ravel()))` , so for a boolean matrix, `norm(M)` is 0.  if `M` is the `False` matrix, 
1. otherwise. use the `ord` parameter of `norm` to tune the function.